# Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 1

Tags: php, google-maps, symfony, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

### General Information

Laravel Version: 5.4
PHP Version: 7.0.15
Operating System and Version: ubuntu 16.04

### Issue Description

[I am upgrading from laravel 5.3 to 5.4 ]
In `composer.json` I have added `"toin0u/geocoder-laravel": "^1.0",`.I have also removed the `config/geocoder.php` configuration file .
There is no Geocoder alias in the aliases section of the config/app.php.

I have added `Geocoder\Laravel\Providers\GeocoderService::class,` in `config/app.php` . but still getting the error when I do **composer update**   or **composer install** .

```

> Nothing to install or update
>   Package egeloen/http-adapter is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use >php-http/httplug instead.
>   Writing lock file
>   Generating autoload files
>   Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postUpdate
>   php artisan optimize
>
> `[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]`
>    `Class 'Toin0u\Geocoder\GeocoderServiceProvider' not found`

```
My composer.json file looks like

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,

"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "toin0u/geocoder-laravel": "^1.0",
    //"toin0u/geocoder-laravel": "@stable",
    "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
    "illuminate/support": "5.4.x",
    "illuminate/console": "5.4.x",
    "symfony/process": "~3.2",
    "barryvdh/laravel-async-queue": "0.6.x",
    "laravelcollective/html": "5.4.x-dev"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.7",
    "symfony/css-selector": "3.1.*",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "3.1.*",
    "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^2.1"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database",
        "app/Models",
        "database/migrations",
        "database/seeds",
        "app/libraries"
    ],
"psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},

 "extra": {
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "0.6-dev"
    }
},

"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
        "php artisan ide-helper:generate", 
        "php artisan ide-helper:meta",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
}
```

}

I was using Class 'Toin0u\Geocoder\GeocoderServiceProvider' in my config/app.php file ,thought it could be the problem as it is unable to find this class so I removed this from there still getting the same error message.
Please Help .
Thank-you in advance !

Edited:
My new app.php looks like this:(I have commented the lines involving Geocoder)

```
<?php
```

/*code after providers */

```
'providers' => [

    /*
     * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
     */
    Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,

    /*
     * Package Service Providers...
     */
    Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
    /*registering the Geocoder Service Provider */

    //Geocoder\Laravel\Providers\GeocoderService::class,


    /*
     * Application Service Providers...
     */
    App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    // App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
    // Way\Generators\GeneratorsServiceProvider::class,
    NoHasl\Providers\FormatServiceProvider::class,
    NoHasl\Providers\GeoIPServiceProvider::class,
    //Toin0u\Geocoder\GeocoderServiceProvider::class,
    Barryvdh\Queue\AsyncServiceProvider::class,

],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Class Aliases
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This array of class aliases will be registered when this application
| is started. However, feel free to register as many as you wish as
| the aliases are "lazy" loaded so they don't hinder performance.
|
*/

'aliases' => [

    'App' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
    'Artisan' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
    'Auth' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
    'Blade' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,
    'Bus' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus::class,
    'Cache' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class,
    'ClassLoader'=> Illuminate\Support\ClassLoader::class,
    'Config' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class,
    'Cookie' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::class,
    'Crypt' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class,
    'DB' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
    'Eloquent' => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class,
    'Event' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::class,
    'File' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class,
    'Gate' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::class,
    'Hash' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,
    'Lang' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::class,
    'Log' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
    'Mail' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::class,
    'Notification' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification::class,
    'Password' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::class,
    'Queue' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::class,
    'Redirect' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::class,
    'Redis' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
    'Request' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
    'Response' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::class,
    'Route' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
    'Schema' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class,
    'Session' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class,
    'Storage' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,
    'URL' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
    'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
    'View' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,
    'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
    'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
    'HTML' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
    'Format' => NoHasl\Format::class,
    'GeoIP' => NoHasl\GeoIP::class,
    'Input' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::class,

],
```

];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the lin `Geocoder\Laravel\Providers\GeocoderService::class,` from the providers list in your `app.php` config file. Then run `composer install` or `composer update`. Once the package is installed you can then go and add the provider back in the `app.php` config file.

If you're unable to install the package then remove the line `"toin0u/geocoder-laravel": "^1.0",` from your composer.json. Then run `composer require toin0u/geocoder-laravel` to perform a clean install.

Comment: I am getting the same error even after removing this. I have also done `php artisan dump-autoload` but still error is same. I think some file is saved and need to be removed for making changes. getting same error even I clear cache . What could be the reason?

Comment: The error is with `Toin0u\Geocoder\GeocoderServiceProvider` so you haven't removed that from your app.php file. Post the full contents of your app.php file.

Comment: I have made this line comment . even I have removed it from composer.json file but the error is still there . bdw Thank-you for your fast response sir. I have shared the contents of app.php above.

Comment: Try running `php artisan clear-compiled` and then continue with whatever you were doing.